# What code language uses these files and structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do some work on a code given to me, but I don't know what the language is.

It has a .sln file towards the top.

It has a .master file with code that looks like this:

```
<div class="page">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMaster" runat="server" BorderColor="#082F48" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="970px">
            <div style="width: 100%;">
                <table id="tblAreaTabs" width="970px" align="center">
                    <tr bgcolor="#05133B">
                        <td align="left">
                            <img alt="image" src="/Images/LogoTall.jpg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: url(/Images/rowBg.jpg); height: 27px" align="left">
                        <td align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" ForeColor="White">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table align="center" width="970px">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        </form>
        </div>
```

In the same folder as .master, there's some .vb and .vbproj files. There's also a web.congig file.

There are various folders for things like CSS and images, and some with more .vb files.

My guess was ASP.NET, but when I made a "hello world" ASP.NET app to compare, they looked nothing alike.

Comment: There are [3 different types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/overview) of asp.net. You could also simply google search "asp:Panel" which appears on the third line in the code (or anything starting with "asp:" for that matter) and get multiple articles about asp.net.

Comment: The `.master` file is a clear indication that it's ASP.NET WebForms, which is on .NET Framework 2.0 through 4.8 (master pages were introduced in 2.0). WebForms is not available on ASP.NET Core.

Comment: `runat="server"` is another clear indication of WebForms. MVC on both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core does not use that attribute for anything.

Comment: Thank you all! This really helps narrow it down, and now I can confidently know what to learn to work on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a likely a ASP.NET Master Pages application. `.sln` is a solution file. Try to open the project using Visual Studio Community (free), for a better experience with it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100)

Comment: "ASP.NET Master Pages application" you mean ASP.Net WebForms!